# Write boost managed shared memory to file

Tags: c++, boost

I hope any expert using the boost managed shared memory can help me. I´m trying to write the memory to a file. I can not figure it out with the boost examples. ¿Can anyone provide me some examples?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you truly need this, I see roughly 2 approaches, at a glance:

1. Copy it

   - use serialization/deserialization
   - or just copy by constructing clones in a different segment manager (obviously linked to a memory mapped file, this time)
2. Use a [Managed External Buffer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/interprocess/managed_memory_segments.html#interprocess.managed_memory_segments.managed_heap_memory_external_buffer). A managed buffer is basically your segment manager on top of some transparent memory buffer. You can decide whether it exists in local process address space, shared memory, or indeed a memory-mapped file.

   This is the *supported* method to use the same segment manager + segment data layout in both.

If you're really desperate you COULD try to bitwise copy the complete shared memory object into a file of equal size and simply open it. This *might* work IFF the `managed_mapped_file` implementation has exactly the same or compatible segement management structure, headers and layout. That's a long call though, and even if it appears to work, it's at best undocumented, and therefore likely invokes undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for `mapped_file`: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/mapped_file.html

It is a memory-mapping API for files, and you can open the same file in multiple processes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have read the documentation, but still I don't know how to convert a shared memory into a file.